# Never include cell value in excel calculation

Tags: excel

tl;dr Is it possible to label cells as 'ignore' (or equivalent) so that if they are included in the range of a SUM function, they are not included in the calculation and therefore outputted value?

I have created a complex table that depicts revenue over the next few years. The table rows run continuously through the months with no break between December of one year and January of the next. I have realised I need to put in a Total column at the end of each year. If I select each Jan column and click insert, I get a vacant column at the end of each year that can be used for my total column (to the left of each Jan). However, I use SUM extensively in each row and I do not want any of the cells in the Total columns to be included in any of the calculations of the cells for the months. Is it possible for me to write my formulae in each Total column cell and then somehow specify that I do not want this value to be included in any calculations at all i.e. is there some sort of 'ignore' label i can apply to these cells? I know the alternative is to manually change each formula, but I have 5 years worth of predictions each with 50 rows and each cell has multiple SUM functions in it...

Answer (score 0):

Say we have values in column **A** from **A1** through **A400**, but some of the items are intermediate subtotals, etc.  We want to sum column **A**, but omit the subtotals.

In column **B** place a ***1*** in rows that you want to process and a ***0*** in rows you want to skip

Then use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A400)*(B1:B400))
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't solve my problem as I would still have to alter all subsequent formulae. Please read the entire question for further information.

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1. Use the SUBTOTAL function to calculate those subtotals, and the AGGREGATE function to do the sum at the end, as it has an option that lets you ignore SUBTOTAL results.
2. Use a PivotTable. You can then easily subtotal by year or whatever else you want.

I would personally go for option 2